# Print With No Margin

Tags: wpf, printing

I am attempting to print a WPF control 4" tall by 3" wide.

I have used a `ScaleTransform` on the control (a `Canvas`) to scale it accordingly; however, when I print to a printer part of the image is cut off (the top and left edges).

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/2c932555-149a-43c6-8ff1-e72a9ed9fe9c):

> The reason of this problem is that the printer provides an unprinted margin around the edge of the paper, but the [`PrintDialog.PrintVisual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx) method intends to print to the edge of the paper. So the area that lies in the unprinted margin around the edge of the paper is clipped.

The thread fails to mention how to retrieve the margins or how to force the printer to ignore these margins. How do I obtain these values so that I can print using WPF without clipping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to combine information from the `PrintDocumentImageableArea` with the `Measure` and `Arrange` members on your `UIElement`:

```
// I could not find another way to change the margins other than the dialog
var result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
{
    var queue = printDialog.PrintQueue;

    // Contains extents and offsets
    var area = queue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket)
                    .PageImageableArea;

    // scale = area.ExtentWidth and area.ExtentHeight and your UIElement's bounds
    // margin = area.OriginWidth and area.OriginHeight
    // 1. Use the scale in your ScaleTransform
    // 2. Use the margin and extent information to Measure and Arrange
    // 3. Print the visual
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying it now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked. I had to add the margins (multiplied by 2 to get the left, right, top and bottom) to the size of the item that I was trying to print. I used this size in the Measure and the Arrange methods (starting the Arrange method at the top, left margin).